# How to order results in union clause in mysql

Tags: mysql

i want to get all records until it is get the value of total but i want to order it DESC by date like in this query :

```
SELECT NULL AS donation_acc_name, NULL AS dopu_purpose, NULL AS dopu_second_purpose, NULL AS dopu_ref_id, NULL AS total FROM dual WHERE (@total := 0) 

UNION 
(SELECT donations.donation_acc_name, dopu_purpose, dopu_second_purpose, dopu_ref_id, @total := @total + dopu_remain_value AS total 
       FROM donation_purposes 
       LEFT JOIN donations ON donation_purposes.dopu_donation_id = donations.donation_id 
       WHERE @total < 5000 AND dopu_id IN (100,136) AND dopu_remain_value > 0 AND dopu_finished = 0 
    ORDER BY donation_purposes.dopu_date DESC)
```

but order by doesn't work!!

Do you have any solution?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: "doesn't work!!" is rather vague in terms of reporting the observed behavior: is there an error message? does the query hang? are unexpected results returned? the resultset is in an unexpected order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define an additional column (as NULL) for the 1st query with the alias `dopu_date` and apply the ORDER BY clause to the result of the `UNION` and not just the 2nd query:

```
SELECT donation_acc_name, dopu_purpose, dopu_second_purpose, dopu_ref_id, total
FROM (
    SELECT NULL AS dopu_date, NULL AS donation_acc_name, NULL AS dopu_purpose, NULL AS dopu_second_purpose, NULL AS dopu_ref_id, NULL AS total FROM dual WHERE (@total := 0) 
    UNION 
    SELECT donation_purposes.dopu_date, donations.donation_acc_name, dopu_purpose, dopu_second_purpose, dopu_ref_id, @total := @total + dopu_remain_value AS total 
    FROM donation_purposes 
    LEFT JOIN donations ON donation_purposes.dopu_donation_id = donations.donation_id 
    WHERE @total < 5000 AND dopu_id IN (100,136) AND dopu_remain_value > 0 AND dopu_finished = 0 
) t
ORDER BY dopu_date DESC
```

Comment: it reordered but get wrong results .. the first record should be 3300 and second is 1787 so it should get 3300 then 1700 as total must be 5000 but it get 5087 for first and 1787 for second

Comment: Your question is about sorting the results. You are sorting by date. Aren't the results sorted correctly by date?

Comment: yes but not as expected .. it should sum also descently

Comment: `ORDER BY donation_purposes.dopu_date DESC` is only sorting by date. If you have a new requirement then post a new question.

Comment: Oh sorry .. your answer is right and it is working fine now .. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Move the ORDER BY outside the second select to act on the while union.

```
SELECT NULL AS donation_acc_name, NULL AS dopu_purpose, NULL AS dopu_second_purpose,
       NULL AS dopu_ref_id, NULL AS total 
FROM dual WHERE (@total := 0) 

UNION 

SELECT donations.donation_acc_name, dopu_purpose, dopu_second_purpose, dopu_ref_id, @total := @total + dopu_remain_value AS total 
FROM donation_purposes 
LEFT JOIN donations ON donation_purposes.dopu_donation_id = donations.donation_id 
WHERE @total < 5000 AND dopu_id IN (100,136) AND dopu_remain_value > 0 AND dopu_finished = 0

ORDER BY donation_purposes.dopu_date DESC
```

Comment: I think there is some wrong in your answer .. why the last bracket ?

Comment: @eng.ahmed You are right.  That was a cut and paste problem.